# Saving terminal windows in mint

Tags: terminal, linux-mint

How can I save all the terminal tabs(with each current pwd in each tab) and terminal window positions.

Comment: Here is an xfce terminal fork, with possibility to save/restore session just from menu: https://github.com/repu1sion/xfce4-terminal

Answer (score 4):

GNOME Terminal (I think Linux Mint with Cinnamon uses GNOME terminal) has two command line switches for that:

```
--load-config=FILE
Load a terminal configuration file
--save-config=FILE
Save the terminal configuration to a file
```

#### Example

- Use `gnome-terminal --save-config=/path/to/the/file` to save the current state to file.
- Use `gnome-terminal --load-config=/path/to/the/file` to load the configuration from the file you saved the config.

#### References

- [Save multiple gnome-terminal layout?](https://superuser.com/questions/72130/save-multiple-gnome-terminal-layout)

Comment: does this save the current working directory of the shell? if not, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: AFAIK, it should save it, according to [this blog post](http://vadim-kirilchuk-linux.blogspot.com/2013/05/gnome-terminal-how-to-save-tabs-and.html) and specifically [this screenshot of the saved config file](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CyNF37Fc208/UYC_3f8MrWI/AAAAAAAAB84/CupC5f1GSdA/s1600/gnome-terminal-tabs3.png)

Comment: Option "--save-config" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.